# How could you give a computer a "natural need"?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

So the idea is that a computer agent would be programmed in two layers, the conscious and unconscious.

The unconscious part is essentially a set of input and output devices, which I typically think of as sensors (keyboard, temperature, etc. to the limit of your imagination) and output methods (screen and speakers notably in the case of a home PC, but again to the limit of your imagination).  Sensors can be added or removed at anytime, and this layer provides two main channels to the conscious layer, an single input and a single output.  Defining what kind of information travels between these two layers is sort of difficult, but the basic idea is that the conscious part is constantly receiving signals (of various levels of abstraction) from the output of the unconscious part, and the conscious part can send whatever it wants down to the unconscious layer through the input channel.

The conscious layer initially knows little to nothing, it is just being completely blasted by inputs from the unconscious layer, and it knows how to send signals back, though it knows nothing about how any particular signal will affect the unconscious part.  The conscious part has a large amount of storage space and processing power, however, it is all volatile memory.

Now for the question.  I would like for the conscious part of the system to "grow" in that it has no idea what it can do, it just knows it can send signals, and so it starts out by sending signals down the pipe and seeing how that affects the sensor data it receives back.  The dead end is that the computer is not initially trying to satisfy a goal.  It is just sending signals around.  To think of it like a baby being born, they need food, or sleep or to be moved out of the sun, etc.  The sensory inputs of the baby are fed to its brain, which then decides to try making use of its outputs in order to get what it needs.

**What kind of natural need can a computer have?**

`What have I tried?`
Thinking specifically about how a baby becomes hungry, I certainly haven't read any research on cat scans perform on crying hungry children or anything, but I thought perhaps a particular signal comes from the unconscious with growing speed constantly which is only satiated when the signals sent back cause the baby to eat.  The conscious brain's job would be to minimize the rate at which each type of signal comes in at.  In other words, the "instinct" of the computer is to limit the rate of each signal coming in.  What other "instincts" could there be?  The problem with this analogy of course is, computers don't need to eat.  Or at least I haven't been able to translate eating to something a computer needs.

`Outside of the scope of this question`
The end goal of this is to teach a computer who knows nothing except how it interacts with the world to play tic-tac-toe.  So another idea I had was to supply a button you could press to manually stimulate the rate of a particular signal entering the conscious when it does something bad or manually soothe the rate of a particular signal when it does good.

Comment: Cool idea, I like it.  Random thought though: when it comes to AI whether or not 'nature does it that way' is of little consequence, if you think a computer should "want"/"need" (I think it's safe to say in this context they're pretty much the same thing until the conscious has learned to distinguish them) something, then make the computer 'want/need' it.  Ultimately you only care if it works or not.

Comment: I'm not so worried about nature as finding a goal for the computer which never ends, and forces the computer to keep doing things in order to more easily satiate the inevitable "need" coming around the corner.  I'm basically looking for something in the unconscious layer that would be regularly affected to force this behavior.  I don't want to tell the system what to do, I want it to figure out how to get what it needs in the most effective way.  Because in a sense, I have a job and go to work to make getting food much easier.

Comment: Can you compare your problem to the reinforcement learning problem and highlight differences?

Comment: @ziggystar, the question isn't about the learning process or the algorithms used to deduce knowledge.  I am not trying to solve a specific problem, but rather build a system which can be taught to solve many trivial problems in more than one way.  **My problem** is giving the computer a less than artificial need to continuously look for better ways to solve those problems rather than solve it and retire.  The rest of the program uses a number of reinforcement learning and other AI techniques, but that is not what this question is about.

Comment: @NL I'm not talking about the ways to solve the RL problem, but about the problem itself. Have a look at the POMDP model then. Does the RL Problem differ from your problem setting? If not, then you'll be able to formulate your issue using terms like 'utility', 'discount factor' and such.

Answer (score 3):

Machine intelligence programs generally start at the Award level on [Mazlow's Hierarchy of Needs](http://www.ict-learningnow.com/) because they don't have a way to perceive Physiological, Safety & Security, or Social needs. However...

At the physiological level the computer feeds on electricity. Plug in a UPS that tells the computer when it is running on battery and you have a potentially useful input for perceiving physiological needs.

Give it the ability to "perceive" that it has "lost time" or has gaps in its time record (due to power failure) and you might be able to introduce the need for Safety and Security.

Introduce social needs by making it need to interact. It could "feel" lonely when lots of time passes between inputs from the keyboard.

Detecting lost time, time passed since last keyboard interaction, and running on battery could be among the inputs available to the unconscious layer that can periodically be bumped to the attention of the conscious layer.

The computer scientists in [Two Faces of Tomorrow](http://www.webscription.net/10.1125/Baen/0671878484/0671878484.htm) approach a similar problem, training a computer sandboxed on a satellite to become aware. They give it those needs by, for example, making it aware that it will cease to function without electricity then providing appropriate stimulation and observing the response.

[The Adolescence of P-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Adolescence_of_P-1) is another interesting work along these lines.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back to this answer.  I didn't realize I was reading a novel until a couple chapters in.

Answer (score 3):

A robot was programmed to believe that it liked herring sandwiches. This was actually the most difficult part of the whole experiment. Once the robot had been programmed to believe that it liked herring sandwiches, a herring sandwich was placed in front of it. Whereupon the robot thought to itself, "Ah! A herring sandwich! I like herring sandwiches."

It would then bend over and scoop up the herring sandwich in its herring sandwich scoop, and then straighten up again. Unfortunately for the robot, it was fashioned in such a way that the action of straightening up caused the herring sandwich to slip straight back off its herring sandwich scoop and fall on to the floor in front of the robot. Whereupon the robot thought to itself, "Ah! A herring sandwich..., etc., and repeated the same action over and over and over again. The only thing that prevented the herring sandwich from getting bored with the whole damn business and crawling off in search of other ways of passing the time was that the herring sandwich, being just a bit of dead fish between a couple of slices of bread, was marginally less alert to what was going on than was the robot.

The scientists at the Institute thus discovered the driving force behind all change, development and innovation in life, which was this: herring sandwiches. They published a paper to this effect, which was widely criticised as being extremely stupid. They checked their figures and realised that what they had actually discovered was "boredom", or rather, the practical function of boredom. In a fever of excitement they then went on to discover other emotions, Like "irritability", "depression", "reluctance", "ickiness" and so on. The next big breakthrough came when they stopped using herring sandwiches, whereupon a whole welter of new emotions became suddenly available to them for study, such as "relief", "joy", "friskiness", "appetite", "satisfaction", and most important of all, the desire for "happiness'.

This was the biggest breakthrough of all.

~from *The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy* by Douglas Adams

**Bonus**

Have a look at Reinforcement Learning.

Comment: @NickLarsen, In all fairness, your question sounds like this is the first day you've ever spent thinking about machine learning. You quantify nothing, and only use vague pseudo-psychology terms in an effort to equate a computer to a baby. In short, you effectively asked nothing, and received an appropriate reply. But yes, reinforcement learning is what you're looking for.

Comment: @Chris S, I have asked something specific, highlighted in bold in my original post.  I have, in fact, spent a very large amount of time thinking about the question, and machine learning in general.  The question is difficult, hence I have not been able to find a workable answer on my own, and hence me asking the community.  I have asked something specific, and this reply is the equivalent of telling me to investigate farming if I ask what's for lunch.  Also, if you look at the time stamps, you will notice the `Bonus` was added after my reply.

Comment: @Chris S, To further clarify, I do not care about the algorithms used in the conscious part, that is another matter entirely.  I am looking for a way to give the computer a less than completely artificial reason to keep exploring what it can do.  This inverts control from the user to the computer, which is the distinction I am after.